# D3.js scrolling bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a simple bar chart:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
var xLPU=d3.scale.ordinal();
var yLPU=d3.scale.linear();
var xLPUAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xLPU)
    .orient("bottom");

var yLPUAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yLPU)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10, "чел.");
var LPUdivision=d3.select("#LPUgraph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
d3.json("LPUdivision.json",function(data){
    xLPU.domain(data.map(function(d){return d.lpu;}))
    .rangeBands([0, width]);
    yLPU.domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.amount; })])
    .range([height,0]);
    LPUdivision.append("g")
    .attr("class","x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xLPUAxis);
    LPUdivision.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yLPUAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("численность состава");
    LPUdivision.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar")
    .attr("x",function(d){return xLPU(d.lpu)})
    .attr("width", xLPU.rangeBand()-5)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yLPU(d.amount); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yLPU(d.amount); })
    .attr("fill","steelblue");

});
```

LPUdivision.json

```
[
{"lpu":"lpu1","amount":"20"},
{"lpu":"lpu2","amount":"40"},
{"lpu":"lpu3","amount":"60"},
{"lpu":"lpu4","amount":"10"},
{"lpu":"lpu5","amount":"80"},
{"lpu":"lpu6","amount":"30"},
{"lpu":"lpu7","amount":"20"},
{"lpu":"lpu8","amount":"40"},
{"lpu":"lpu9","amount":"60"},
{"lpu":"lpu10","amount":"10"},
{"lpu":"lpu11","amount":"80"},
{"lpu":"lpu12","amount":"30"},
{"lpu":"lpu13","amount":"20"},
{"lpu":"lpu14","amount":"40"},
{"lpu":"lpu15","amount":"60"},
{"lpu":"lpu16","amount":"10"},
{"lpu":"lpu17","amount":"80"},
{"lpu":"lpu18","amount":"30"}
]
```

Here is output graphic:
[Lpu graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDLZe.png)
As you can see it's messy a lot. I need all the lpu labels to display. So I suppose that there should be some scroll bar, but I didn't find good example with scroll bar on graphic. Any advises?
Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efTr7/1/)

Comment: would be easier if you include a jsfiddle with html and jquery code.

Comment: check answer i posted and let me know if it helps.. i will try to adding json to your fiddle and update you

Comment: Ok, but I've added it already. Changed to variable jsonlike

Comment: updated fiddle in answer .. here is your code updated http://jsfiddle.net/efTr7/2/

Comment: Updated with scroll http://jsfiddle.net/efTr7/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try as below

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"> 
      <div id="LPUgraph"> </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.outer {
    width: 700px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.inner {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
#LPUgraph{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/efTr7/4/)