# How to use chart in JavaScript with large data set

Tags: javascript, charts, large-data, c3.js

I need to visualize the bar chart with Javascript. So I'm used C3 JS to visualize the chart. Simply I'm using this Bar chart as follows,

```
<div id="chart"></div>

<script>

var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ],
      axes: {
        data2: 'y2'
      },
      types: {
        data2: 'bar'
      }
    },
    axis: {
      y: {
        label: {
          text: 'Y Label',
          position: 'outer-middle'
        },
        tick: {
          format: d3.format("$,") // ADD
        }
      },
      y2: {
        show: true,
        label: {
          text: 'Y2 Label',
          position: 'outer-middle'
        }
      }
    }
});

</script>
```

[image]

But the problem is when X-axis consists of the large data set Chart getting cramped. I have more than 700 data.

[image]

Have any possible way to avoid this? can I add scroll bar between primary and secondary X-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google, such a wonderfull thing ;)

https://c3js.org/samples/interaction_zoom.html

or this

[C3 / D3 bar chart with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395029/c3-d3-bar-chart-with-horizontal-scroll)

Comment: your welcome. thanks to you I know now a great alternative to flot... :)